# Adding python variables to jinja counter

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I want to add the python variables from flask in the jinja template
Suppose 'a' is a python variable(a list of int values) brought into the jinja template using render_template function from flask :

```
{%set count = 0%}
{%for element in a%}
      {%set count = count + element%}
{%endfor%}
{{ count }}
```

The value of 'count' should be updated but it still prints 0 on the screen
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most recent versions, due to [scoping rules](https://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-1.1/docs/build/scopes.html), your version doesn't work.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
{% set count = namespace(value=0) %}
  {% for element in a %}
    {% set count.value = count.value + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
{{ count }}
```

Comment: {{ count.value }} or you get <Namespace {'value': #####}>